# Diferencia de concatenar datos en Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Agradezco de antemano a las personas que me puedan ayudar con esta consulta ya que soy nuevo en la programación.

Estoy tomando un curso de Python y estaba practicando las condicionales y me surgió la siguiente duda:
¿Por qué al concatenar con las comas no me dan ningún error pero cuando concateno con el signo de más `+` me da el siguiente error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

He leído que en Python no se pueden concatenar datos diferentes.
Si al poner el signo de más agrego la variable nota de esta manera `str(nota)` realiza el `print` pero el dato lo convierte a `string`.

Disculpen si la pregunta no tiene lógica o es algo obvio para los que tengan experiencia pero no quiero dejar vacíos o dudas.

```
nombre = "Jean Carlos"
nota = 4

if nota >= 8:
    print("Felicidades" , nombre , " Tu nota es" ,nota , "." , "Eres un excelente alumno")
else:
    print(nombre , "Lamentamos que tu nota se" , nota , "Perdiste el año")
```

Comment: ¿Es la pregunta específica de Python 3.7? Parece que no, pero lo mismo se me escapa algún detalle. En cualquier caso, siempre etiquetamos también con [tag:python] para que quede todo bien ordenado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de este ejemplo:

```
name = "alfred"
edad = 23

print(name,edad)
```

Que nos da como resultado lo siguiente

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 4, in
>    TypeError: must be str, not int

Obtenemos entonces que Python necesita para concatenar que los valores sean del mismo tipo de dato; es decir `int` con otro valor `int` o `string` con otro valor `string`

De modo que si ahora hacemos:

```
name = "alfred"
edad = 23

print(name,edad)
```

Obtenemos como resultado lo siguiente

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

alfred 23
```

Ahora también tenemos la posibilidad de aplicar algo similar a un `casteo de datos` es decir indicarle que alguno de los dos valores sea del mismo tipo que el otro, de tal modo que si hacemos lo siguiente

```
name = "alfred"
edad = 23

print(name+' '+str(edad))
```

Obtenemos como resultado

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

alfred 23
```

Es decir pasamos el valor de *23* a la función `str()` que lo casteará a un tipo de dato cadena

Con el método `type` podemos leer que tipo de datos es, de modo tal que en el siguiente script puedes ver como la variable `edad` en un primer momento es de tipo `int` pero después del *cast* se vuelve de tipoo `str`

```
edad = 23
converted = str(edad)

print(type(edad))       //imprime int
print(type(converted))  //imprime str
```

Este es el resultado

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu pronta respuesta =). Tengo una duda más y si la variable edad estuviera guardada en una base de datos y al imprimirla le realizo el casteo de datos para mostrar en el print, ¿dicho valor cambiaria de Int a String en la base de datos por el casteo? o solo cambiara el valor para mostrarlo en el print........ Saludos

Comment: @CarlosCode el valor que tiene en la base de datos se mantiene, cuando haces un `SELECT` y lo cargas en una vista y lo pasas de `str` a `int` por ejemplo solo cambia para la vista pero el valor almacenado sigue conservando sus propiedades

Comment: Eres lo máximo. Gracias por tu ayuda, soy nuevo en stackoverflow donde puedo calificar tu respuesta.

Comment: si la respuesta te fué útil entonces del lado izquierdo de mi aporte existe una palomita gris, que al darle clic se pone en verde y se entiende que ya aceptaste dicha respuesta

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda. Exitos amigo

Comment: Creo que el primer ejemplo de código esta mal, pues debería funcionar y de hecho es igual al segundo que funciona. Seguramente querías poner `nombre+edad`

Comment: Te comento que cada ejemplo lo probé en la consola antes de ponerlo aquí

Comment: No abulafia así como respondí procedí desde la consola usando la misma versión de Python que el OP y ese es el resultado obtenido; pero si tienes un aporte que nos clarifique la duda pues eres bienvenido

Comment: @abulafia disculpa el comentario anterior, no era ni para ti ni para esta respuesta, me equivoque a quien le queria responder

Comment: Ah. Ya no entendía nada :-)

Comment: Borro todos mis comentarios anteriores entonces

Comment: @abulafia no hay problema amigo, no me molestan tus observaciones, prometo en cuanto tenga tiempo ponerme a revisar lo que dices